# how to recover a path from a file(HttpPostedFileBase)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httppostedfilebase

I want to recover the path from any file

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select file to import")]
[Display(Name = "Arquivo ")]
public HttpPostedFileBase Arquivo { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Arquivo)
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Arquivo, new { type = "file", name="Arquivo" })
```

Through the model I already have access to inputStream, however, I really need the file path to another logic.

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: The path as in where it is stored on the server, or where it was stored on the client?

Comment: You won't be able to retrieve the client path from the client for security reasons

Comment: the file will always come from the same server, only in different folders. The application has all the necessary permissions to access that server.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517228/uploaded-file-not-saving-to-file-system/30519935#30519935

Comment: i'm not trying to save file, i'm receiving files from client side.

Answer (score 1):

If you POST your file using HTML form, you cannot get full filepath for security reasons.